# pytest doesn't execute test/__init__.py file

Tags: python, pytest, python-packaging

I have the following problem:
I have project and a small library there and a test directory for lib, something like that:

project\

+mylib\

++test\

In test__init__.py I have the following code:

```
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, "test_data_files")))
```

So just updating syspath to be able open some files with test data.
When I run test by right-click on directory in Pycharm it executes succesfully, but when I run

```
python -m pytest lib/test
```

It doesn't executes test/**init**.py file and fails with  FileNotFoundError, as it can find test data files.

What is the reason of such behavior, and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you run pytest in `lib/test`, it will look for `test_*.py` files and run the tests therein. As you found out, it does not import the `test` package so that the `__init__` is never imported.
If you run pytest "globally", it imports the packages it runs tests in so that your `__init__` is imported.

To fix, you could make use of pytest's [`conftest.py`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixture-functions).

Comment: I've created conftest.py file in lib/test package:

      import os
      import sys


      def update_syspath_for_test_file_searching():
    SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),  os.path.expanduser(__file__))))
    sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, "test_data_files")))

But it still can't find files. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I the one can use fixtures for it?

Comment: Did you double-check that `SCRIPT_DIR` is set to what you expect it? I'd also make sure that the `conftest.py` is run at the time you want it to run.